# How do I repair a detached SB600 flash head tilt/rotate lock-release button?

Tags: nikon, flash, repair, sb-600

The rubber cover that I press to tilt/rotate the head of my SB-600 flash has come off after years of abuse, and it looks like the original adhesive has dried out.

Can anyone recommend some non-detrimental glue that I can use to fix it, rather than send it back to Nikon? I'm based in the UK so I may not be able to buy some of the adhesive that you US guys have access to.

---

Thanks all - I'm going to try Araldite Rapid this weekend and I'll do a followup post if it works really well (or badly).

Comment: Wow, I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Matt what are the two surface materials? loads of contact adhesives available but some are more specific than others about what they stick to,
more info will help.
btw matt as the flash expert why does a pttl flash image get progressily darker as you zoom in?

Comment: Hard plastic and a rubber or rubber-like substance. Unfortunately I don't really know how to get more specific than that.

Answer (score 2):

Okay folks - I did the deed at the weekend,it worked, and here's a summary. Note! It worked for me: YMMV.

1. Cleaned off what appeared to be a semi-solid impact adhesive from the pseudo-rubber "push" button- *don't* lose the centre spring! I used extreme care and the edge of a vegetable  knife as a scraper;
2. Mixed a portion of Araldite Rapid,about the size of a filter-cigarette tip;
3. Moved the flash head so that it's vertical;
4. Try a dry run: place the rubber button into it's correct position and make sure no bits stick up. When you're happy,
5. Applied adhesive carefully to outer edges of the button and also *carefully* to the corresponding metal area on the SB-600 and join the rubber to the metal;

When you're doing this initial lining-up, try and get the lettering that says "push" to be the correct orientation!

Wrap your button and flash gun with Sellotape (clear tape) and leave it for an hour: longer if you can. Depending on the ambient temperature, you may want to clean off any excess.

Hope this helps!

(NB.. Some adhesives seem to based on flammable compounds, and I was reluctant to use these on a device that can generate kilovolts, and sparks)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: a synthetic rubber based adhesive is what you want

From the service manual for Nikon SB-600 speedlight, you need to use Adhesive J67017 - rather cryptic.  Googling this finds another Nikon service manual that says this product ID is for Cemedine 575.  This is a japanese brand of Chloroprene Rubber adhesive - so any synthetic rubber based adhesive should do the job (search "synthetic rubber adhesive" on ebay to find plenty of reasonably priced options).